# How do I store String value in registry and access it later in the flow? (Mule ESB 3.7)

Tags: mule

I have 2 flows with different inbound endpoints and the second flow is started upon completing the first flow using app.registry.flowName.start(). Now, I have a variable in the first flow that that I would like to access in the second flow.I searched some forums online which says I will have to define a global variable in mule context which I am doing it in a custom java class. How do I set a variable to mule context and access it later? 
Note: Using flow reference

How is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide your code snippet.

Comment: Hi @THeron,  public class RegisterObject implements MuleContextAware { 
 private MuleContext muleContext;
 public void setMuleContext(MuleContext muleContext) {
  this.muleContext = muleContext;
 }
 public void storeObject (String importId) {
    try {
     SaveObject saveObj = new SaveObject();
     saveObj.setImportId(importId);
     muleContext.getRegistry().registerObject("importObj", saveObj);    
  } catch (RegistrationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
 }. I am getting a null pointer exception when I am trying to register the object.

Answer (score 0):

MEL allows you to register objects to the registry within the Mule flow configuration. The example shows how to register and lookup an element from the Mule registry.

```
<expression-component>
    app.registry['myObj']= payload
</expression-component>

<logger level="INFO" message="#[app.registry['myObj']]" />
```

Be aware that the registry is not the best location to store application data. For application data the Mule Object Store is the right place for it.